# Python NumPy log2 - How to make it a negative log?

Tags: python, numpy

I just started working with Numpy because I want to use their log method. I am trying to do -log2(79/859) but can only see how to do log2(74/571) which outputs a negative value when it should be positive. Read the Doc but don't see how to make it a negative log?

How can I fix this?

```
print(np.log2(79/859))
```

Output

`-2.947893569733893`

Output I want

`2.947893569733893`

Tried searching through NumPy Docs

Comment: log2 of the number that is < 1 is negative. Not sure why do want it to be positive.

Comment: Do you just want the negative result or always the absolute value of the result?

Comment: The log (base 2) for 74/571 is indeed negative 2.948. If you want it to be always positive, you could use `np.abs(np.log2(...))`

Comment: "I just started working with Numpy because I want to use their log method" - wait. The sole purpose for which you have chosen to use NumPy is that NumPy can do logarithms? The standard `math` module [already has that](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log2). You don't need NumPy just to take a logarithm.

Comment: Thank you GusSL, that's what I was looking for. Using -log and log give the same answer but -log makes the value output positive. Needed an easy way to do this to a whole lot of values to make it easier to insert for a project.

Comment: You ... just add a negative sign.

Comment: Just posted an answer clearing things up.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows a poor understanding of a simple concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I posted in my comment, if you always want a positive value for your logarithm, you can use an absolute value:

```
np.abs(np.log2(74/571))
# 2.948
```

Also, as suggested above, you don't need the *NumPy* library if you only want to use logarithms. You can accomplish the same with the `math` standard module and even with built-in functions:

```
import math

abs(math.log2(74/571))
# 2.948
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(-np.log2(74/571))
```

> 2.947893569733893

if I correctly understand what you want.